# In "@headlessui/react", how to pass 'Popover' 'open' prop to it's parent component

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am using the "Popover" component from "@headlessui/react" & I want to take action when the popover open/close without changing the default open/close behavior.

So I was thinking of passing the 'open' prop of the "Popover" component to a wrapper component & then execute the fn that I want to execute inside a useEffect. However I am not sure how I can do this.

https://headlessui.dev/react/popover

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're on the right track with the wrapper component. However, I'd suggest passing the function you'd like to execute down to the popover and running it in a useEffect there.

Here's the idea (based on one of the examples from the Headless UI site):

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Popover } from '@headlessui/react'
import { ChevronRightIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid'

function PopoverContent({ open, func }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (open) {
      func()
    }
  }, [ open ])

  return (
    <>
       <Popover.Button>
         <span>Solutions</span>
         <ChevronRightIcon
           className={`${open ? 'transform rotate-90' : ''}`}
         />
       </Popover.Button>

       <Popover.Panel>{/* ... */}</Popover.Panel>
    </>
  )
}
  

function MyPopover() {
  const functionToExecuteOnOpen = () => {
     // do something
  }

  return (
    <Popover>
      {({ open }) => (
        <PopoverContent
          open={open}
          func={functionToExecuteOnOpen}
        />
      )}
    </Popover>
  )
}
```

You can remove the if statement in the useEffect and simply call the function if you want it to run every time `open` changes (regardless of the value).

Comment: This call to `useEffect` breaks the rules of hooks: https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning

Comment: Which specific rule does it break?

Comment: The call is not at the top level of a function component or custom hook.

Comment: The anonymous function that starts with `{({ open }) => {` is the function component. It's a function component because it's a function that returns React elements. It worked in my quick example that I tried, but it's possible the Popover might call it differently so I'll add another component layer to make sure it works.